# How to get subject of gmail letter with curl?

Tags: curl, imap, gmail, lua

I use `curl` in my Lua program to get new mail list.
I am trying to send request like this

```lua
local head_command = "curl --connect-timeout 30 -fsm 30"
local server       = "imap.gmail.com"
local mail         = "***"
local password     = "***"
local port         = 993
local request      = "-X 'FETCH 86 BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)]'"
local curl = string.format("%s --url 'imaps://%s:%s/INBOX' -u %s:%q %s -k", head_command, server, port, mail, password, request)
helpers.async(curl, function(stdout, exit_code)
  naughty.notify { text = stdout, timeout = 0 }
end )
```

But only I get is

```
* 86 FETCH (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)] {54}
```

And I get response like this for any `FETCH` command.

I can get message `HEADER` if specify `UID` in url directly like

```
imaps://%s:%s/INBOX;UID=86/;SECTION=HEADER
```

It outputs this

```
Delivered-To: bugaev.nsu@gmail.com

Received: by 10.140.91.106 with SMTP id y97csp1976911qgd; Mon, 25 May 2015
 18:50:08 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.112.142.232 with SMTP id rz8mr19609586lbb.74.1432605008430;
 Mon, 25 May 2015 18:50:08 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <bugaevamv@mail.ru>
Received: from f342.i.mail.ru (f342.i.mail.ru. [217.69.140.238]) by
 mx.google.com with ESMTPS id b3si5030682lbd.117.2015.05.25.18.50.07 for
 <bugaev.nsu@gmail.com> (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
 bits=128/128); Mon, 25 May 2015 18:50:08 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of bugaevamv@mail.ru designates
 217.69.140.238 as permitted sender) client-ip=217.69.140.238;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of
 bugaevamv@mail.ru designates 217.69.140.238 as permitted sender)
 smtp.mail=bugaevamv@mail.ru; dkim=pass header.i=@mail.ru; dmarc=pass (p=NONE
 dis=NONE) header.from=mail.ru
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mail.ru;
 s=mail2; h=Content-Type:Message-ID:Reply-To:Date:MIME-Version:To:From;
 bh=vOFnL58jZvcsH24k/6XvHT0DhLLtNvAaCxTAZUvggn4=;
 b=GJpRK8wJfOfrrlW6KycI6CDBUPTlQNBSNmAswE+5M67hdePFUeoHkakQdh8ziPtmOPsSWCwLs2spcqXjTkQ1Ny2raWBrbVaaFKPSxzdi7m6JGfwJ3Snkv1DMGBhGVCqBOIwVj7iCdnBEzYQhCMgZ6UvjDNv15PReV5MiJzECnG0=;
Received: from [194.125.255.143] (ident=mail) by f342.i.mail.ru with local
 (envelope-from <bugaevamv@mail.ru>) id 1Yx40N-0001gA-0m for
 bugaev.nsu@gmail.com; Tue, 26 May 2015 04:50:07 +0300
Received: from [194.125.255.143] by e.mail.ru with HTTP; Tue, 26 May 2015
 04:50:06 +0300
From: =?UTF-8?B?0JzQsNGA0LjQvdCwINCR0YPQs9Cw0LXQstCw?= <bugaevamv@mail.ru>
To: =?UTF-8?B?0JrQuNGA0LjQu9C7INCR0YPQs9Cw0LXQsg==?= <bugaev.nsu@gmail.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: Mail.Ru Mailer 1.0
X-Originating-IP: [194.125.255.143]
Date: Tue, 26 May 2015 04:50:06 +0300
Reply-To: =?UTF-8?B?0JzQsNGA0LjQvdCwINCR0YPQs9Cw0LXQstCw?= <bugaevamv@mail.ru>
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <1432605006.905230278@f342.i.mail.ru>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--ALT--rUEeoQugXy3WMzk9UAxdG7pumUrVItQl1432605006"
X-Mras: Ok
X-Spam: undefined
```

But how can I get message `SUBJECT` this way?

Comment: Does "_message header_" mean the full set of message header lines? If so you could extract the subject from that set. Mostly it's plain text (but not always - see RFC2822). Or are you asking what a specific Gmail implementation is that will retrieve just a message subject? It's not really clear what you're actually asking for help with.

Comment: Yes, I can get full message header, but I can't find SUBJECT field in it. I will edit my question, just a minute.

Comment: Looking at what you've provided I'd suggest that in this particular message there is no message subject.

Answer (score 0):

I'm think that understand what is problem. Gmail sends response in several steps, curl outputs only first. I write lua code that can retrieve message SUBJECT. Something like this

```lua
local socket    = require "socket"
local ssl       = require "ssl"
local format    = string.format

local server   = "imap.gmail.com"
local port     = 993
local login    = "user@gmail.com"
local password = "***"
local params = {
    mode = "client",
    protocol = "tlsv1",
    verify = "none",
    options = "all",
}

local conn = socket.connect(server, port)
conn = ssl.wrap(conn, params)
conn:dohandshake()
conn:settimeout(5)

conn:send(format("123 LOGIN %s %s", login, password) .. '\r\n')
conn:send("123 EXAMINE INBOX" .. '\r\n')
conn:send("123 FETCH 86 BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)]" .. '\r\n')

local result = ""
while result do
    result = conn:receive()
    if result then
        print(result)
    end
end

conn:send("LOGOUT")
conn:close()
```

It outputs

```
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 176.114.188.238 q1mb64314748lfc
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LITERAL- SPECIAL-USE APPENDLIMIT=35651584
123 OK bugaev.nsu@gmail.com authenticated (Success)
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotPhishing $Phishing)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] Flags permitted.
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1] UIDs valid.
* 352 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDNEXT 1283] Predicted next UID.
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 218991]
123 OK [READ-ONLY] INBOX selected. (Success)
* 86 FETCH (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)] {37}
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?UmVbMTJdOiA=?=

)
123 OK Success
```